# Are humans unusual, compared to other animals, in not understanding the mechanics of sex instinctively?

Tags: behaviour, sex, epigenetics, animal-psychology

To begin with a personal anecdote: there was a period in my childhood, which I can remember clearly, in which I was aware of sexual reproduction as a fact, but the mechanics of it remained a fascinating mystery. From conversations with friends - both at the time and later, recalling earlier times - and also from looking at popular culture, my experience seems pretty typical.

There are numerous instances from history of adults who were ignorant of sex to a degree which - from the perspective of our own time, where graphic content is ubiquitous and sex education mandatory - is quite baffling. A couple of royal examples:

1. [Anne of Cleves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_of_Cleves) seems to have believed, from a conversation with the Countess of Rutland in February 1640, that her husband kissing her goodnight was sufficient to impregnate her.
2. [Louis XVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XVI) famously took seven years to consummate his marriage with Marie Antoinette. The rumours about there being an anatomical problem, i.e. phimosis, seem to have been discredited. Neither does there seem to have been any emotional barrier; the two always seemed to like each other, and eventually had four children together. But there was no consummation until Joseph II gave his brother-in-law some practical advice on the matter, after which he described Louis and Marie Antoinette as 'a couple of complete blunderers'.

Looking at the topic more systematically, [this article](https://nines.org/print_exhibit/861) summarises several scholarly sources. Said page discusses one book in particular called ***The Facts of Life: Creation of Sexual Knowledge in Britain 1650-1950*** (1995) by Roy Porter and Leslie Hall. Although I have not read this book myself, the article I mentioned states:

> Imagine a wedding night where neither party had any idea how the mechanics of sex functioned. Imagine a new bride so terrified of the “rude” action her husband tried to commit, she runs home to her parents and asks for an annulment the next day[...] These terrifying circumstances where women had no reproductive or sexual knowledge prior to real-life experience were all a reality, according to Roy Porter and Leslie Hall

So that's my case for humans lacking an instinctive understanding of the mechanics of sex. **What about other animals?** To the best of my knowledge, humans do seem to be unlike other mammals, at the very least. Any dog-owner can testify to the naturalness with which both male and female dogs play their respective parts. I remember a sheep farmer once telling me grimly that, in some breeds of sheep, it was a struggle to keep the male lambs from impregnating their mothers.

**And what about other species of ape?** With humans, there is a stock character in literature of the midwife/cunning woman/duenna/etc who advises the bride what to expect on her wedding night, and this character seems to have at least some basis in reality. There are also male equivalents to such a figure, e.g. the advice Joseph II gave to Louis XVI I mentioned above. Do we see any comparable roles being played among other species of ape? If so, could this be considered an example of epigenetic inheritance - analogous to the famous example of a rat mother licking her pups - and/or animal culture?

Comment: Absent sufficient sex education, teenagers get each other pregnant quite efficiently whether or not they intend to, suggesting they figure it out as well as any other animals. I question how you'd ask a dog, sheep, etc whether they understand the motions they're going through or are just following their instinctual programming.

Comment: only humans is weird societies that don't let children see adults have sex have this problem. humans learn about sex the way they learn about almost everything watching adults.

Comment: Giant pandas have been purported to benefit from instructional videos, but I found that to be not well attested when I looked for references for an answer.